# API 26 runtime permission & android.os.FileUriExposedException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, rxpermissions

My app needs below permissions. Which has been incorporated in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus"/>
```

After upgrading to API 26

> (targetSdkVersion 26)

Some functionality is not working. As I need to incorporate runtime permission. I am using [RxPermission](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions/) .
The problem is my most of the implementations are placed in helper class(not inside main activity).
when I am trying to use helper library getting error - .[image: Can not resolve constructor]
I have tried with the following options too -

> RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions((FragmentActivity) mContext);

As [RxPermission](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions/) require Fragment as target.Can we ask user all the permission in the main activity? A sample code will help me. Project code for [reference](https://github.com/kaku2015/WeatherAlarmClock/blob/master/WeAC/src/main/java/com/kaku/weac/db/LocalAlbumImagePickerHelper.java#L76)

**[Fixed]**
Now I am calling from the activity. [Reference](https://github.com/kaku2015/WeatherAlarmClock/blob/4ff531449894f6156a37d2369ebbcec29d9f5705/WeAC/src/main/java/com/kaku/weac/activities/LocalAlbumActivity.java#L101)Code changed -

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions=new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions.request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        .subscribe(granted -> {
            if (granted) {

                //LogUtil.e(LOG_TAG, "Granted external permission");
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_album);
                ViewGroup backGround = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.background);
                MyUtil.setBackgroundBlur(backGround, this);

                initAdapter();
                assignViews();

            } else {
                // Oups permission denied
            }
        });
```

**[New error]**
I am getting  `android.os.FileUriExposedException:` error. Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        // 返回
        case R.id.action_back:
            myFinish();
            break;
        // 拍照
        case R.id.action_capture:
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            // FEATURE_CAMERA - 后置相机
            // FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT - 前置相机
            if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
                // 访问相机类型
                int requestType;
                // 截取主题壁纸
                if (mRequestType != 2) {
                    requestType = REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_THEME;
                } else { // 截取二维码logo
                    requestType = REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_QRCODE_LOGO;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(MyUtil.getFileDirectory(this, "/Android/data/" +
                        getPackageName() + "/capture/temporary.jpg"));
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, requestType);
                overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.zoomin);
            }
```

> Error

```
 Process: com.bisw.weac, PID: 20997
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bisw.weac/capture/temporary.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:944)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10480)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4522)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
    at com.bisw.weac.activities.LocalAlbumActivity.onClick(LocalAlbumActivity.java:222)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6877)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26069)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: I'm assuming the library requires a `FragmentActivity` instance, which you are not supplying - your `mContext` is the `Application` looking at your naming of the parameter. Consider passing the correct `Context` on the method calls inside your helper, not the constructor, as they should have a short lived scope you won't want to hold a reference to.

Comment: Thanks @mark-keen. I am calling the helper class like this LocalAlbumImagePickerHelper.getInstance(LocalAlbumActivity.this). Do you want me to change here?

Answer (score 1):

> My app needs below permissions

Note that your app cannot hold `MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYTEMS` unless it is signed by the firmware signing key or is installed on the privileged app partition (mostly for rooted devices).

> Can we ask user all the permission in the main activity?

You do not have a choice, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions/#important-read). According to those instructions, RxPermissions only works if you request the permissions from `onCreate()` of your `Activity` (or possibly `onCreate()` of your `Fragment`, though that part is unclear).

> A sample code will help me

In addition to documentation, [the RxPermissions GitHub repository](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) has a sample app. [Here is the v0.9.3 edition of that sample app](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions/tree/v0.9.3/sample).

Comment: @CommnsWare thanks for clarification. Last point as I said I can do easily from the activity. But I need to refer fragment. from helper class where I don't have fragment.

Comment: @BiswajitDas: By the time you call `getThumbnail()` from anywhere, you need to ensure that you have your runtime permission. Then, you do not need an `RxPermissions` instance in `getThumbnail()`. Your "helper" class appears to be a singleton; a singleton cannot and should not be attempting to request runtime permissions.

Comment: @CommnsWare friend inside main activity I am still getting the same error - Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/thumbnails from pid=25888, uid=10229 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: @BiswajitDas: Perhaps you are not waiting until you get permission before calling `getThumbnail()`.

Comment: @CommnsWare Please see the updated code above **Edit 1**

Comment: @BiswajitDas: You do not appear to be using RxPermissions correctly. `ensure()` is meant to be used as part of an overall `Observable` chain, where you do not attempt to use the permission until your subscriber is invoked. In particular, `ensure()` is not a blocking call; you will not have permission when it returns. If you are unfamiliar with RxJava and `Observable`, you might wish to use something other than RxPermissions. For example, [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) does not use a third-party library.

Comment: finally I am able to fix. it

Comment: @CommnsWare I am getting **FileUriExposedException** error. Updated desc **newError**

Comment: @BiswajitDas: You can find [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed) by searching on major search engines for `FileUriExposedException`. If you have additional concerns, please ask a new question.

Comment: saw the suggestion so need to replace file with content?

Comment: @CommnsWare post the new  question. Could you please help me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255297/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-writing-android-support-v4-conte/53257038#53257038

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to fix it calling from main class.

```
 RxPermissions rxPermissions=new RxPermissions(this);
    rxPermissions.request(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .subscribe(granted -> {
                if (granted) {
                    customDefineBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    LogUtil.e(LOG_TAG, "Granted external permission");

                } else {
                    // Oups permission denied
                }
            });
```